# Trouble configuring sendmail to relay mail

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, ufw

I am trying to configure sendmail and ufw on an ubuntu server (ServerA) so that another server (ServerB) can send mail through it. In my /etc/mail/access file I have the following line (a.b.c.d is the IP of ServerB):

```
Connect:a.b.c.d    RELAY
```

My ufw status shows the following rule I added:

```
25/tcp                     ALLOW       a.b.c.d
```

When I telnet from ServerA I get through:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

When I telnet from ServerB I don't (w.x.y.z is the IP of ServerA):

```
telnet w.x.y.z 25
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I did restart the sendmail daemon after editing the access file.

What could I be missing? Something in sendmail.mc?

**Edit**:

```
netstat -an|grep -w 25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: Could you paste the output of `netstat -an|grep -w 25` (on server A) into your question?

Comment: I will read it.

Comment: Removing some lines from sendmail.mc to get it to listen to the outside world fixed the problem. Thank You.

Comment: No worries.  The best thing to do under these circumstances is to delete your own question, so it doesn't hang around with no formal answer forever; there should be a "delete" link at the bottom.  And do a bit more research before asking another question <grin>!

Answer (score 0):

## Sendmail listening only on the localhost interface

[Sendmail FAQ 4.22: Why can't I receive external mail?](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/general_issues_faq/#4.22)

> Several vendors have changed the way that sendmail is run. They decided that most people need a client-only version of sendmail. So it is listening only on the localhost interface [...]

The problem has been located by test suggested by [MadHatter](https://serverfault.com/users/55514/madhatter): `netstat -an|grep -w 25`